# how to push data into seperate json model folder in sapui5 onsubmitting button

Tags: sapui5

View1.view.xml

```
<mvc:View controllerName="Register.controller.View1" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m">
    <App>
        <pages>
            <Page title="{i18n>title}">
                <content>
                    <f:SimpleForm>
                        <f:content>
                            <Label text="FirstName" />
                            <Input value="" id="a1" width="50%" />
                            <Label text="LastName" />
                            <Input value="" id="a2" width="50%" />
                            <Label text="username" />
                            <Input value="" id="a3" width="50%" />
                            <Label text="Password" />
                            <Input value="" id="a4" width="50%" />
                        </f:content>
                    </f:SimpleForm>
                    <Button id="btn1" type="Accept" text="Submit" press="onPress" />
                </content>
            </Page>
        </pages>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

Controller

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function(Controller, JSONModel) {
    "use strict";
    var sValue, data, oModel, selectedVal, textAreaVal;

    return Controller.extend("Register.controller.View1", {

        onPress: function() {
            //get the value of the selected item in the combobox
            selectedVal = this.getView().byId("a3").getValue();
            //get the textarea value
            textAreaVal = this.getView().byId("a4").getValue();

            var oModel = new JSONModel(jQuery.sap.getModulePath("Register", "model/model1.json"));
            this.getView().setModel(oModel);
            oModel.data.push({ selectedVal: selectedVal, textAreaVal: textAreaVal });
        }
    });
});
```

I have created this but getting push is not a function

Comment: I think you're missing some code

Comment: What do you mean with "push data into separate json model folder"? Are you trying to save something on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the data incorrectly. There is no `data` array inside `oModel`, it is an object (push is for array's)

You should set the data using the model's `setData` method instead:

```
oModel.setData({ selectedVal: selectedVal, textAreaVal: textAreaVal });
```

### Updated answer

I understand you want to update an array inside your model. In that case, first retrieve the array from the model, then push the new object, and then finally store the updated array back into your model:

```
var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
var aData = oModel.getProperty("/data");
aData.push({ selectedVal: selectedVal, textAreaVal: textAreaVal });
oModel.setProperty("/data", aData);
```

See this working example: https://jsbin.com/kosaji/edit?html,output

Comment: i have created the json model in model folder as below { "data" :[ ] } have to save the data into model

Comment: Even then, `data` is **not** a property of your model `oModel` (which you can see in the debugger). It is a class, not a simple object, so use the getters and setters instead

Comment: i have tried with updated answer,but values are not getting stored in data which is an array in model

Comment: What's wrong with the code and example I provided in my answer?

Comment: If you see the example I provided, you see the values are stored in `data` array in your model... not sure how I can help you further, this is perfectly working code (open the console tab in JSBin and you'll see the data added to the model)

Comment: Thank you so much,its working now.,Thanks for your time